# IntelliJ GUI Designer component properties to bound class?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Is there a way to generate a code from the component's properties in the GUI designer to the bound class?

Let's say I modified the margins of `JPanel`, I wanted it to generate that line of code in the bound class.

Comment: A [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html) does not have margins. Do you mean you are adding an empty [Border](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) to the `JPanel`?

Comment: In IntelliJ, Jpanel have `margin` property. I'm usng the latest version of IntelliJ and SDK 17 of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | GUI Designer | Generate GUI into: **Java source code**.

Rebuild the project, all the custom properties you set will appear in the bound .java file.